# How to replace navigation link with navigation button in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Hello I am new in Wordpress. I have create one website as part of my project, but I have problem like I have link in my top navigation menu, but i want to replace that navigation link to navigation button. Here I want to replace that link to button. For example home, aboutus like in link but I want home, aboutus in button.

Answer (score 0):

Step to change menu link and menu label

1) Login with wp-admin

2)Appearance - > Menus

Here can can change menu label or link

JQuery Code for add Home button

```
$("li.current_page_item > a > span").eq(0).text('').append('<input type="button" value="Home"/>')
```

if you need further any help tell me.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I want to change that link to button in design. so how can I do it?

Comment: could you show me url where you working or need more explain?

Comment: <li class="current_page_item">
<a href="http://kalyansoft.com/wp1">
<input type"button" value="Home"/>
</a>
</li>..................u need like that